# Spring MVC 404 error when using annotation-driven configuration

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am getting the following error:

> The requested resource (/SpringWebApp/) is not available.

My Web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>MVC</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
     </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>        

    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>MVC</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

MyFirstController:

```
package com.assyst.SpringWebApp;

import java.util.Locale;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;



@Controller

    public class MyFirstController 
    {


        @RequestMapping(value="/")
        protected ModelAndView ServletContainer(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception 
                {

                        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("HomePage");
                        model.addObject("msg", "welcome to spring mvc hello world");
                        return model;


                }
    }
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

      <annotation-driven />
    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->
   <!--<beans:bean name="/" class="com.assyst.SpringWebApp.MyFirstController"></beans:bean> -->

     <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
     <beans:bean name="response" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

      <context:component-scan base-package="com.assyst.SpringWebApp" />



</beans:beans>
```

The url I am using to access it is: `http://localhost:8080/SpringWebApp/`
My application server is jboss 7.

What am I doing Wrong here?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you deploying your app? Is `/SpringWebApp` really your context path?

Comment: Do you have a `HomePage.jsp` in `/WEB-INF/views`? Adding the logs here would help.

Comment: Yes /SpringWebApp is my context path and HomePage.jsp does exist in /WEB-INF/views I have added screen shots so that you can verify for both questions. Thank you

Comment: My Log4j configuration is as follows:                             <!-- Root Logger -->
 <root>
  <priority value="debug" />
  <appender-ref ref="console" />
 </root>                                                  and my console does not show any error messages is there some where else that I should check?

Comment: I found the error it turns out my application was not being compiled I didn't have the problems tab opened I guess. However, I have the spring-osgi-annotations jar file it is talking about and I am not sure why it is complaining I have been trying to change my pom.xml file to get maven to download it again with no luck. And I tied a suggestion in stack overflow by adding a dummy library and updating my project using maven, but still no luck. Any ideas Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You guys were right /SpringWebApp Context was the problem I switched it to SpringMVCWorking2 and it worked. The Spring-osgi-annotation.jar file issue it turns out is just a sporadic issue that occurs in eclipse I deleted the error message and then reran the project and it was gone.

Thanks for your help